# select a specific text from a line of text

Tags: javascript, csv

For example if this is a line of text which is placed inside a file : **The sun rises in the East**.

Also, in an HTML page it reads a text from a text box (say *'rises'*). I need to check this text with the text inside the file to find a match. And I need to return the text value inside the **file**. How it can be performed? I am using JavaScript.

```
function Upload() {
var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
    if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
          var table = document.createElement("table");
var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
{   
    var row = table.insertRow(-1); 
    var cells = rows[i].split(",");
    for(var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++)
    {
        var cell = row.insertCell(-1); 
         cell.innerHTML = cells[j]; 


    var radio = document.createElement('input');
    radio.type = 'checkbox';
    radio.name = 'check';

}         
}
 var button = document.createElement('button');
    button.textContent = 'Send';
cell.appendChild(button);

var dvCSV = document.getElementById("dvCSV");
dvCSV.innerHTML = "";
dvCSV.appendChild(table);
        }

        reader.readAsText(fileUpload.files[0]);

    } else {
        alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
    }
} else {
    alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
}
}
```

Comment: which files you want to use? and did you try anything?

Comment: I am using CSV files, and displayed succesfully.

Comment: how you are loading csv file, show in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Read the text from the file i.e The sun rises in the East.

Now,compare this value to the value entered in the textbox by the user using `string.search(textbox value)`, where string="text read from the file".